# Hesped on satmar rov and connection to Parshas noach

Tags: rabbis, parashat-noach

Does anyone know where I could find reb hutners hesped on the satmar rav and specifically the connection he makes to the lion by Parshas noach

Comment: https://matzav.com/the-last-lion-the-satmar-rov-rav-yoel-teitelbaum-ztl-on-his-30th-yahrtzeit/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the words mentioned in a comment above is from page 8 of [The Jewish Observer Nov. 1979](https://agudah.org/wp-content/uploads/1980/09/JO1979-V14-N04.pdf) regarding the levaya of the Satmar Rebbe.
[image]

It mentions Rav Hutner using the lion comparison, but at an earlier occasion and not at the levaya or at a *hesped*.

I have tried looking for reports on the levaya from the Agudas Yisroel's דאס אידישע ווארט to maybe get a fuller picture but have not yet been successful.

An earlier article re: the actual levaya appeared on pp. 3-4 of the [September Jewish Observer of that year](https://agudah.org/wp-content/uploads/1980/09/JO1979-V14-N02.pdf) but did not include a list of *maspidim*.

Do you know for a fact whether Rav Hutner said an actual *hesped* for the Satmar Rebbe?

Comment: Thought that is when he mentioned yet but I guess not